# how to load data in react-bootstrap-table partially by using pagination

Tags: reactjs, dynamic, pagination, react-bootstrap, react-bootstrap-table

I am getting data partially from backend (let's say 10 rows per api call) and I want to call the api on page change but I am unable to find any relevant option in react-bootstrap-table pagination. Is there any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"react-bootstrap-table2-paginator" takes a prop of onPageChange where you can do what you want with the page number
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-bootstrap-table-paging-example-forked-rqhyd5

```
  <BootstrapTable
        bootstrap4
        keyField="id"
        data={products}
        columns={columns}
        pagination={paginationFactory({ sizePerPage: 5, onPageChange:(page)=>console.log("DB CALL with page" + page) })}
      
      />
```

Comment: ps: Check the console on codesandbox link

Answer (score 0):

if you dont want to see pagination selectbox , you can add sizePerPageList property in paginationFactory settings,

form example;

```
 <BootstrapTable
    bootstrap4
    keyField="id"
    data={products}
    columns={columns}
    pagination={paginationFactory({
      sizePerPageList: [
        {
          text: "5",
          value: 5
        }
      ],
      onPageChange: (page) => console.log("DB CALL with page" + page)
    })}
  />
```